# libtool slowing down gdb

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, libtool

I have a larger C++ programm with lot of templates which i want to debug. Unfortunately gdb takes several minutes to read the symbols.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html contains lots of options for debugging.

Which options would you suggest to make gdb faster/more usable.

**Update**: It looks like the slow down is caused by libtool. If gdb is launched via libtool --mode execute it is slow. If gdb is launched gdb .libs/foo it is reasonable fast. Any ideas why is much slower?

**Update**: Another suggestion was -fvisibility=hidden see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: I'm surprised GDB indexes (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Index-Files.html) haven't been mentioned? Your first debug symbol load will be just as slow as usual, but with the `save gdb-index` command and some `objcopy` magic you can speed up _subsequent_ debug symbol load times greatly. In your build, after the binary with debug symbols is produced, I would run GDB in batch mode to generate and incorporate said index into it, and presto a rapidly loadable debuggable binary. This is especially worthwhile to include on build machines.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes using -fdebug-types-section can make things a bit faster.  It isn't guaranteed though.

Several minutes to load ... I wonder how big this executable is.  If I were desperate I might try only compiling selected modules with debug info.  Or perhaps look to see if it is a gdb bug.  If it is split into an executable and some shared libraries, and some parts don't change very often, you could also look into using the "gdb index" feature (see the manual) to speed up the loading of debuginfo for those modules.

Comment: -fdebug-types-section did not make a difference. The Executable is ca. 18MB unstripped and 3.2MB stripped. gdb version is 7.7, i will try to upgrade to a version from git to see if it makes a difference

Comment: 7,7 is new enough that you probably won't see much difference.  That doesn't sound so very big to me, I'm surprised it takes minutes.

Comment: It looks like the slowness is caused by launching gdb via libtool --mode execute. (see the Update)